# Arduino: (char)Serial.read() returns as ⸮ (reversed question mark)

Tags: arduino

I am trying to write the `(char)Serial.read()` to the Serial. But I don't want to do that if it is NULL. And when it is, it just writes `⸮` in the Serial. And I want the if-statement I made below, to ignore these.

```
char serialInput = (char)Serial.read();
if(serialInput != NULL) { //I also tried "⸮" instead of NULL, didn't work either
  Serial.println(serialInput);
}
```

How do I sort these NULL cases off?

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.read()` returns -1 if there are no data. Of course you have to check it before you cast it to `char`. And there is `Serial.available()` which returns count of characters available for read so you can check before you read. See some basic examples in IDE Examples menu.